# Headset cable (with 6 cores)

Tags: wire, headphones

First of all I am most definitely not an expert but I still wanted to try repairing my Razer Kraken headset and cut of the cable to re-solder them onto the small "regulator pcb" (because one had been torn off) (it's that little thing that has a toggle-mute button and a wheel to adjust the volume). When opening the casing of said thing I saw that there where 4 small wires inside the cable going from the pcb to the plug but 6 going from the pcb to the headset. I then opened up the headset and found that two of them were labeled SPR, one was labeled MIC- and a fourth one MIC. The remaining two weren't labeled. My Question is: Why are there these 2 extra cables? Or if SPR is speaker right then why are there two cables for speaker right?
[One answer I came up with is that these are the ground for the respective Speaker and that in the small pcb these are all combined into one - is this correct?]

SOLUTION: The answer provided below solves my question however there was still another problem I had to solve: there were not only 4 but 5 connections going from the pcb to the plug (2 of them being ground). BUT the one for the mic was actually "hidden inside" the ground cable [one of the ground connections was weapped around the mic cable which made it look like one bigger copper wire]

Comment: I am an experienced solderer I've never been able to successfully repair headphones.

Comment: Would you mind to post one or more pictures? @VoltageSpike, it is possible to solder such tiny things, I've done it.

Comment: @thebusybee apparently I can't... - the website won't let me... But I could describe it more if that would help? Would there be something that would help you help me figure this out? Also could my theory be true (the one in the brackets at the bottom)

Comment: Your theory is probably true, because each speaker needs two lines, and the microphone needs two lines, two. To let us be sure some picture of the PCB with all labels readable would help much.

Comment: Why refused the website to insert pictures? Can't you use the little picture icon at the top of the edit box? Is it a reputation thing?

Comment: @thebusybee perhaps it is a problem with mobile version. There are several pcbs: one inside the headset where there are two cables (red and blue/copper[striped]) both labeled SPR. Then there are on the same pcb two cables where one is labeled MIC (white) and the other one MIC- (copper). Then there is a seperat pcb where the last two are coming out of. However they are not labeled at all (I think they are the ones for the Left speaker and would be something like SPL because they seem to be connected to that speaker on that side.

Comment: Copper is almost always double-used as return line and shield. If you have the opportunity use some source for earphones (like any audio device) and connect the assumed cables of each speaker. Experiments make things clear. ;-) ... I'm sorry, here at my place it's night and I have to fetch some sleep. Good luck!

Comment: @thebusybee thanks - it's the same for me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say you are correct. If there are 6 cables, (assuming that this is a normal pair of headphones with only a mic and two speakers) then they would probably be 3 ground cables and 3 cables going to each respective part of the headphone. This would mean that there would be a ground cable for the right speaker, the left, and the mic.

Usually, the darker cable out of the pair is ground. Sometimes this may not be the case. You could also see if there are any stripes or white lines on the cable. If so, then that cable would be the positive line. 
As well, in your case, I would assume that all bare copper cables are ground. To make sure of this, you could always use a multimeter and check the voltages. If you put the red probe to one of the speaker lines and the ground probe to ground you should be able to make out which line is positive just by looking at the polarity on the multimeter.

One last piece of advice, you should look at some teardown videos of the Razor Kraken. You should hopefully find a video that will tell you which cable is which.

Comment: For the ones (of the 4 cables) leading from the smaller pcb to the plug they used red for the right speaker and green for the left. As there are the same colors among the 4 cables that could be the audio lines I suppose that they used the same color for left/right.

Comment: There are no DC voltages on speakers.

Comment: @thebusybee yeah you’re correct. I’ve been working with to much digital design and theory that I forgot that speakers can operate with both negative and positive voltages.

Comment: :-D Well, they not even **can**, they have to, they receive AC. Actually it is not *alternating voltage* but *alternating current* (that's what "AC" means [not that I assume you don't know this, just for the casual reader]) which controls the membrane which generates the sound waves which we finally hear.